# How do I return an Ajax 'failure' from an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I came across an AJAX call which had these three actions upon response:

```
success: function () {
    alert('Success');
},
failure: function () {
    alert('Failure');
},
error: function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
}
```

I'm trying to return a "failure" inside an ASP.NET controller but not sure this is possible:

e.g.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CallFromAjax()
    {
        if (0 > 5)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
```

I know why this doesn't work - the response is still successful, and what I would be doing is processing the `true` or `false` inside the Ajax `success` method.

But what would I actually need to do to make it respond with "failure"??

Is a failure actually the lack of response (e.g. maybe from internet going down) so can't be emulated?

How do I respond with FAILURE and how can I respond with an ERROR?

Comment: Set a response status code other than 200 in else condition.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more googling after only finding results for `error` and `success` and yes, it was basically a timeout issue - so this could be tested by implementing a `sleep` or `wait` function on the server I guess:

> What is Ajax failure?
> The $. ajax method lets you set a timeout in milli seconds. When a timeout happens, The fail callback is called, with errorThrown set to "timeout". The request is aborted, meaning that even if the response arrives later on, your done callback is not called by jQuery.